# Edit a file in /etc using shell scripting?

Tags: shell-script, sed

How do I use `sed` to edit the file `/etc/heat/heat.conf`?

I want to add the new lines under the default section

```
[DEFAULT]
rabbit_host =controller
rabbit_password =RABBIT_PASS
```

Comment: Research and Try yourself before asking

Comment: Is this a task you got at school?

Comment: what exactly do you want to change and why? what is "heat"?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `/regexp/` address to find the line containing `[DEFAULT]`, and then an append (`a`) command to add lines under it. Pass `-i` to `sed` to have it modify the file in-place (you might want to run without it first to make sure it's doing the right thing; it will output what the changed file will look like without actually changing it):

```
# sed -i '/^\[DEFAULT\]$/a rabbit_host =controller\nrabbit_password =RABBIT_PASS' /etc/heat/heat.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have a file `/tmp/a` with the contnet

```
hello my friend
```

You can use sed to replace strings:

```
sed -i 's/hello/hi/g' /tmp/a
```

this will result in:

```
hi my friend
```

see: `man sed`

Also you can add lines without `sed` to a file by using `>>`:

```
echo "I like you">>/tmp/a
```

Comment: But `echo "I like you">>/tmp/a`. It will not replace anything , It just append new thing

Comment: Yes, like i said ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the requester has found a solution by now but just in case.

This request is ideal for application crudini
it is available for all the major linux dustibutions
for example the following will add a line to `DEFAULT` section of `/etc/heat/heat.conf`

```
crudini --set /etc/heat/heat.conf DEFAULT mysetting true
```

The section:

```
[DEFAULT]
rabbit_host =controller
rabbit_password =RABBIT_PASS
mysetting = true
```

will update if entry already in conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Old school `ed` approach

```
ed -s test <<EOF
/^\[DEFAULT\]$/
a
rabbit_host =controller
rabbit_password =RABBIT_PASS
.
w
q
EOF
```